# What is the fastest way to travel on foot?

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

There are two ways of moving forward in a quicker manner than the basic run; sprinting, and dashing. Which movement option allows you to travel on foot the fastest? I've been jumping and dashing because it looks quicker, but it might just be a placebo effect.

Comment: I feel like this is the case for any game... jumping always makes it seem faster. In Warhammer Vermintide, the characters will sometimes comment on one another if they are jumping too much and state things like "you look ridiculous."  I think this is the way the devs went about trying to tell you that jumping doesn't make moving faster.  Also, I think animations can have an impact on whether or not its faster.

Comment: Jumping in Andromeda definitely hinders fast travel. Depending on the height of the jump, the character starts to stagger if he lands.

Comment: @Scorch91 All jumps, no matter the height, seem to cause a short period of slowness, as does dashing.

Comment: I feel like the run dash is the fastest but haven't tested it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, spamming evade is the fastest way to move without a vehicle. I have observed this in multiplayer where sprinting after somebody who is dashing results in them moving away from you.

Jumping results in a period of slowness after landing while the landing animation plays.

Comment: The Explorer profiles's Biotic Blink moves you further than the jump jet or biotic evade. That's probably the fastest way to move.

Comment: How about sprint jumping and then dashing? That is my goto move

Comment: jumping = landing animation